# Entity Data Model Wizard Gets Exception When Trying to Add a New Oracle Connection

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, odac, entity-data-model

I'm trying to generate/update an edmx model from an oracle database and I need to create a new connection to that oracle database. When I click "Test Connection" it succeeds but when I click "OK" it gives the following error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

VS 2017 error when adding new connection to update edmx model
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and @Micke answer below did not resolve. I posted it to the Oracle .Net Tools Forum [Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object From VS2017 EF Data Model Wizard](https://community.oracle.com/message/14985436#14985436).

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue after a brand new installation of VS2017.

1. Installed VS2017 (enterprise edition, in my case).

   - Previously ODT didn't work in the community edition, but Oracle might have fixed that.
2. Installed [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html)

   - ODT broke VS2017 and I had to do a "repair", which fixed the problem where VS2017 wouldn't even start. This is where a started getting the problem you described.
3. Reinstalled [ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for
   Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

   - It was previously installed for VS2015.

Now, everything works as expected and I'm able to e.g. refresh my EF6 models.