# Generating ef edmx faild: operation not valid due to current state of the object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, oracle12c, odp.net, edmx-designer

Im trying to add an edmx model in my. Net project that is connected to an oracle db.

I have installed the oracle developer tools for vs2017 and oracle client 12.1.

After i set up the connection string in and want to generate the edmx i get an error: "operation failed due to current state of the object" and i can't find the solution..

I've tried reinstalling both vs2017, oracle client and oracle developer tools but none of it worked..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this link](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/):
It's explaining how to configure entity framework 6 with database-first and oracle.

And also I found this solution for the error you get:
["Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" when trying to add a new connection in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619948/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-when-trying-to-a)